# in dart i am not able to use user details?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

error:

> The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [chatter_box] lib\helperServices\auth.dart:27)

code:

```
UserCredential result = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);

User? userdetail = result.user;
SharedPreferenceHelper().saveUserEmail(result.user.email);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you're facing came from null-safety, the value that you're getting from the validator method can be either `null` or either a `String`, so you may want to update your code to this example:

```dart
SharedPreferenceHelper().saveUserEmail(result.user.email!);
```

You can learn more about null safety on official documentation:

https://flutter.dev/docs/null-safety